# Jquery UI Autocomplete not showing results properly after ajax call

Tags: ajax, post, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement an autocomplete functionality in django application.
My view is as following

```
@require_POST
@login_required
def search_players(request):
    search_query = request.POST.get('search_query')
    team_ids = request.POST.getlist('team_ids[]')
    players = PlayerData.player.filter(name__icontains=search_query, current_team_id__in=team_ids)
    results = [{'id': player.id, 'name': player.name} for player in players]
    return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

it is returning results in following format

```
{'results': [{'id': 317144, 'name': 'Sharne Mayers'}]}
```

Below is the autocomplete code that I have implemented

```
$('#player-search').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search-players/',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
            data: {
                'search_query': request.term,
                'team_ids[]': [$("#team-one-info").data("team-id"),$("#team-two-info").data("team-id")]  // Replace with your list of team IDs
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.results)
                response(data.results);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,  // Minimum number of characters to trigger search
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Add selected player to the list of selected players
        var selectedPlayers = $('#selected-players');
        var selectedPlayersIds = $('#selected-players-ids');
        var playerPill = $('<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary ml-1"></span>');
        playerPill.text(ui.item.name);
        playerPill.data('player-id', ui.item.id);
        selectedPlayers.append(playerPill);
        // Update the hidden field with the list of selected player IDs
        var playerIds = selectedPlayersIds.val().split(',');
        playerIds.push(ui.item.id);
        selectedPlayersIds.val(playerIds.join(','));
        // Clear the search field
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am getting the proper results back. I have checked using console.log
[image: results in the console]

But I am not able to see the results properly in the autocomplete dropdown. All is see is this
[image: autocomplete dropdown]
I have ensured the the following css files are indeed loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
```

I have also tried different variations of success method such as

```
success:response
```

or using a map function but nothing seems to work. What am I missing? Please help

Comment: Hi, can you change `'name'` to `'value'` in your backend code when generating json and try again ?

Comment: Thanks, changing the code to this finally worked  [{'value': player.id, 'label': player.name} for player in players]